# How to get if data exist in array in php

Tags: php, laravel

I am making **laravel** project.
I need to get data list from request.

**So should get this data if data exist next.**

I used below code...

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($request->post('pickup_location')); $i++)
{
    if($request->post('meeting_ids')[$i])
    {
        $meeting_profile = MeetingPoint::findOrFail($request->post('meeting_ids')[$i]);

        $meeting_data = array(
            'pickup_location' => $request->post('pickup_location')[$i],
            'pickup_type' => $request->post('pickup_type')[$i],
            'pickup_time' => $request->post('pickup_time')[$i],
        );
        
        $meeting_profile->fill($meeting_data);
        $meeting_profile->save();
    } else {
        $meeting_profile = new MeetingPoint;

        $meeting_data = array(
            'holiday_id' => $profile->id,
            'pickup_location' => $request->post('pickup_location')[$i],
            'pickup_type' => $request->post('pickup_type')[$i],
            'pickup_time' => $request->post('pickup_time')[$i],
        );
        
        $meeting_profile->fill($meeting_data);
        $meeting_profile->save();
    }
}
```

But there is this error:

[image]

[image]

How can I get next data list with that logic?

Comment: One of your `$request->post('...')` calls is returning `null`. It would help narrow down the problem if you knew what line caused the error

Comment: No, please see carefully issue screenshot.
Not because of that.

Comment: So this is compare of array with no index?
right?

Comment: Yes. your idea is right. there are issue from that.

Comment: Or you can set required tag in blade So you can without this step in Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please do like below

```
<?php
  $array1 = [
    "Orange" => 100, 
    "Apple" => 200, 
    "Banana" => 300, 
    "Cherry" => 400
  ];

  if ( array_key_exists("Banana", $array1) )
    echo "Array Key exists...";
  else
    echo "Array Key does not exist...";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do like below...

```
        for($i = 0; $i < count($request->post('pickup_location')); $i++)
        {
            if(isset($request->post('meeting_ids')[$i]))
            {
                $meeting_profile = MeetingPoint::findOrFail($request->post('meeting_ids')[$i]);

                $meeting_data = array(
                    'pickup_location' => isset($request->post('pickup_location')[$i]) ? $request->post('pickup_location')[$i] : null,
                    'pickup_type' => isset($request->post('pickup_type')[$i]) ? $request->post('pickup_type')[$i] : null,
                    'pickup_time' => isset($request->post('pickup_time')[$i]) ? $request->post('pickup_time')[$i] : null,
                );
                
                $meeting_profile->fill($meeting_data);
                $meeting_profile->save();
            } else {
                $meeting_profile = new MeetingPoint;

                $meeting_data = array(
                    'holiday_id' => $profile->id,
                    'pickup_location' => isset($request->post('pickup_location')[$i]) ? $request->post('pickup_location')[$i] : null,
                    'pickup_type' => isset($request->post('pickup_type')[$i]) ? $request->post('pickup_type')[$i] : null,
                    'pickup_time' => isset($request->post('pickup_time')[$i]) ? $request->post('pickup_time')[$i] : null,
                );
                
                $meeting_profile->fill($meeting_data);
                $meeting_profile->save();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This isset function is checking function if variable is defined.
So it will be true.

Comment: hey can u add explanation as well,  so other user will also get benefit form your answer , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Arr Helper function to more clean and organized code.

```
        $values = $request->all();

    for($i = 0; $i < count(Arr::get($values, 'pickup_location')); $i++)
    {
        if($id = Arr::get($values, "meeting_ids.{$i}"))
        {
            $meeting_profile = MeetingPoint::findOrFail($id);

            $meeting_data = array(
                'pickup_location' => Arr::get($values, "pickup_location.{$i}"),
                'pickup_type' => Arr::get($values, "pickup_type.{$i}"),
                'pickup_time' => Arr::get($values, "pickup_time.{$i}"),
            );

            $meeting_profile->fill($meeting_data);
            $meeting_profile->save();
        } else {
           ...
        }
    }
```